# Gmap3 marker right click menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I have used this example to get a right click menu working. http://gmap3.net/examples/context-menu.html

I want to modify it so that instead of right clicking on the map to view the menu, you right click on a map marker and see it.

UPDATE:

fiddle created: http://jsfiddle.net/WEZVX/1/

see the right click menu opening when map is right clicked. trying to make it open when marker is right clicked instead.

Comment: The menu object is not available at the time you are calling it, try posting the code where you create the menu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, I have done it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEZVX/2/